# animating with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

The animation has been done with CSS only. How do I achieve the same animation effects using jQuery?
https://jsfiddle.net/20ge4vsz/2/

I tried this:

```
function main() {
  $('.mydiv').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('mydivNew myspanNew', 200);
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Didn't work..

Comment: May I ask why to do a hover effect using jQuery when CSS does that better?

Comment: @LGSon: No reason. Just trying things out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I achieve the same animation effects using jQuery?

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20ge4vsz/5/)

You change these 2 CSS rules names like this

```
.mydivNew {
  width: 155px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #20b2aa;
  border: 2px dotted #20b2aa;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px 0px 15px;
}

.mydivNew .myspan {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 69px;
}
```

And your jQuery to this

```
function main() {
  $('.mydiv').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('mydivNew', 200);
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

---

*And you could write up your script like this instead*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mydiv').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('mydivNew', 200);
  });
});
```

---

Updated based on comment, using jQueryUI

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20ge4vsz/6/)

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.mydiv').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('New', 300).find('span').toggleClass('New', 300);
  });
});
```

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 155px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px dotted #20b2aa;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 20px 0px 15px;
  color: white;
}
.mydiv.New {
  background-color: #20b2aa;
}
.myspan {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 65px 0px 0px 69px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.myspan.New {
  margin: 40px 0px 0px 69px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      
<div class="mydiv">
  <span class="myspan">A</span>
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
  <span class="myspan">B</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The duration parameter of toggleClass won't have any effect unless the transition statement inside both the '.myspan' and '.mydiv' classes in the CSS are removed. But removing them stops animating the alphabet. How do I get around that?

Comment: @George That is not a duration parameter, it is a [state parameter](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I intended using [jQueryUI.](https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: @George Well, that is another question, accept this and post a new with new requirements ... note to setup your fiddle with the proper version of jQueryUI as well

Comment: Hey man, I'd accept it anyway. :p But please, can you help me with that..